# Textbox becomes invisible when background image is set

Tags: android, background-image, android-edittext, textfield

I have this weird problem. Whenever I set a background image for the EditText field, it becomes invisible. However, when I type alphabets, they do appear at the place of the text field but the textbox is invisible.

The code is pretty simple with a EditText field in a xml file with the image being set in the xml file itself.
Why is this happening ?

**My layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="15"
        android:background="@drawable/temp" >
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My TutorialAct.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    writeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    writeText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_bar);
    writeText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    writeText.setKeyListener(null);
    writeText.setText(textString);
}
```

[image: Image I want to use.]

Comment: Post the layouts and the code.

Comment: Did you try setting the background resource to a solid color, not to a drawable?

Comment: yes. setting to a solid color works but drawable does not.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the background resource you are overriding the default 9 patch background resource set by the theme.

Comment: Is there are way to solve that? Can you explain a little more on that? Thanks.

Comment: you could do your own 9patch

Comment: you mean like create my own 9patch image and then set it as a background iamge ?

Comment: One more thing is that if I use any other image (eg. @drawable/img1); it works, the textbox appears with the background image. However, if I use temp.png, it doesn't work.

Is that related to 9patch image overriding?

Comment: I have added the image above and testing on a LG G Pro phone.